# Showing If A Function Is Convex/Concave

Tags: calculus

I have to show wither the two following functions are convex:

$f_1(x)=1+6x-7x^2$ and $f_2(x)=1+6x+7x^2$

Now I want to apply the condition that this is convex iff we have $f(y)\geq f(x)+\nabla^T f(x)(x-y)$

So for $f_1$ we have:

So I have that $\nabla^T f_1(x)=6-14x$  right?

So then if we choose $x=y=0$ then we have that
$1+6y-7y^2< 1+6x-7x^2+(6-14x)(x-y)$? and so this function is not convex.

On the other hand for $f_2$ we have that:

$\nabla ^Tf_2(x)=6+14x$ so we need to show that:

$1+6y+7y^2\geq 1+6x+7x^2+(6+14x)(x-y)$ right? But this doesn't seem to be true either so I am a bit confused?

Any help on where I may have gone wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: In this case you can use second derivatives to check whether a function is concave/convex

Comment: You have to change $x-y$ to $y-x$. In this current form, that's not the right way to show that a function is convex. For a reference, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_function).

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is a continuously differentiable function then, convexity is equivalently to the inequality (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_function)) $$f(y)-f(x)\ge f'(x)(y-x),\ \forall\ x,y.$$

Let $f(x)=a+bx+cx^2$. Note that $f'(x)=b+2cx$. In our case, $f$ is convex if and only if $$a+by+cy^2-a-bx-cx^2\ge (b+2cx)(y-x),$$

or equivalently $$b(y-x)+c(y^2-x^2)\ge b(y-x)+2cx(y-x),\ \forall\ x,y\in\mathbb{R}, $$

or equivalently $$c(y^2-x^2)\ge 2cxy-2cx^2,\ \forall\ x,y\in\mathbb{R},$$

or equivalently $$cy^2-2cxy+cx^2\ge 0,\ \forall\ x,y\in\mathbb{R}.$$

Therefore $$c(y-x)^2\geq 0,\ \forall\ x,y\in\mathbb{R}.$$

Can you conclude that this is true if and only if $c\ge 0$?

Remark 1: the problem with your solution is that you are verifying the wrong inequality, indeed, the right hand side of your inequality must be $y-x$ and not $x-y$.

Comment: Yes as $(y-x)^2$ is always positive. In my question I had $(x-y)$ instead of $y-x$ which generated some of my confusion. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It is much easier to look at the second derivatives. A function $f$ is concave if $f^{\prime\prime}(x)<0$ and convex if $f^{\prime\prime}>0$.

In your case this gives $f^{\prime\prime}_1(x)=-14$, so $f_1$ is concave (so you were right, it is not convex). Furthermore, $f^{\prime\prime}(x)=14$ and so $f_2$ is convex.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will do in future. However in reference to my second part why does my condition not give the result?

Comment: I thought that it didn't hold as if I take $y=0$ and $x=1$ then I seem to have $1\geq 34$ which is false?

Comment: Ah I have $x-y$ instead of $y-x$ which is where (some) of my confusion was coming from. Thanks for the help

Comment: Also I'm not sure if your definition of convexity is correct. I tried to check it, but I can't find this type of definition anywhere. Where did you find it? It looks to me as a cut-off Taylor series.